# What kind of object do I need to use the options parameter of fix_multiple_files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, autopep8

I need to create a simple script for fixing indentation in python scripts of the repository. I found `fix_multiple_files` in autopep8 module:

```
import autopep8

autopep8.fix_multiple_files('/home/playrix/work/ci-teamcity/scripts/', options={'recursive': 1})
```

I'm getting this every time I run the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/playrix/work/ci-teamcity/scripts/1.py", line 4, in <module>
    autopep8.fix_multiple_files('/home/playrix/work/ci-teamcity/scripts/', options='')
  File "/home/playrix/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 3897, in fix_multiple_files
    filenames = find_files(filenames, options.recursive, options.exclude)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'recursive'
```

Comment: That's designed to take an [`argparse.Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object), by the looks of it.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how to call it from my script? ```argparse.recursive``` doesn't help much.

Comment: Well what did you `argparse.recursive` to *be*? You need to build an object with the appropriate attributes, *like* the Namespace object. There are many ways to achieve this: `__getattr__`, `namedtuple`, ...

Comment: What about ```namedtuple```? What kind of data must be in?

Answer (score 0):

How correctly noticed johnsharpe it was `argparse.Namespace`. And the best way to get it was:

```
opt = autopep8.parse_args(arguments=['recursive', '--in-place', '--aggressive'])
```